# Angular CDK drag drop with (reactive) forms

Tags: angular, angular-reactive-forms, angular-cdk

I have this example : https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-asevei?file=app%2Fcdk-drag-drop-sorting-example.html

everything works, but *while* *dragging* the selectbox 'resets' to the first value in the list.

is there any way to fix this? It's only visual, but quite jarring for the user. I have tried using the `cdkDragPreview` option, but couldn't get it to work.

**Component:**

```js
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { CdkDragDrop, moveItemInArray } from '@angular/cdk/drag-drop';
import { FormBuilder, FormGroup, FormArray } from '@angular/forms';

@Component({
    selector: 'cdk-drag-drop-sorting-example',
    templateUrl: 'cdk-drag-drop-sorting-example.html',
    styleUrls: ['cdk-drag-drop-sorting-example.css'],
})
export class CdkDragDropSortingExample {

    myForm: FormGroup;

    constructor(private fb: FormBuilder) {
    this.myForm = this.fb.group({
        title: ['title'],
        items: fb.array([
        fb.group({
            name: fb.control('1'),
            note: fb.control('quux')
        }),
        fb.group({
            name: fb.control('2'),
            note: fb.control('bar')
        }),
        fb.group({
            name: fb.control('3'),
            note: fb.control('baz')
        })

        ])
    })
    }

    drop(event: CdkDragDrop<string[]>) {
    moveItemInArray(this.myForm.get('items').controls, event.previousIndex, event.currentIndex);
    moveItemInArray(this.myForm.get('items').value, event.previousIndex, event.currentIndex);
    }
}
```

**Template:**

```html
<form [formGroup]="myForm">
    <input formControlName="title" />
    <div cdkDropList id="foo" class="example-list" (cdkDropListDropped)="drop($event)">
        <div class="example-box" *ngFor="let item of myForm.get('items').controls" cdkDrag>
            <span cdkDragHandle>drag</span>
            <div [formGroup]="item">
                <input type="text" formControlName="name">
                <select formControlName="note">
                    <option>foo</option>
                    <option>bar</option>
                    <option>baz</option>
                    <option>quux</option>
                </select>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    {{ myForm.value | json }}
</form>
```

Comment: how did your drag n drop form project evolve. I'm working on a similar project. Would you like to chat ?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I have revised @Amir Fawzy's answer by adding a variable in getting the current active note which shows upon dragging the selected box.

**TS:**

```
activeNote: string;
enter(i) {
  this.activeNote = this.myForm.get('items')['controls'][i].get('note').value;
}
```

**HTML:**

```
<div cdkDropList class="example-list" (cdkDropListDropped)="drop($event)">
  <div [id]="i" class="example-box" *ngFor="let item of myForm.get('items').controls; let i=index;" cdkDrag #elem="cdkDrag" (mouseenter)="enter(i)">
    <span cdkDragHandle>drag</span>
    <div [formGroup]="item">
      <input type="text" formControlName="name">
      <select formControlName="note">
        <option [hidden]="elem.moved">{{activeNote}}</option>
        <option>foo</option>
        <option>bar</option>
        <option>baz</option>
        <option>quux</option>
      </select>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

[Here's a duplicate on Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-asevei-kzhw4x?file=app%2Fcdk-drag-drop-sorting-example.html)..

Comment: both yours and @Amir Fawzy's answers led me to a slighly different solution shown here :

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-asevei-wwblpi?file=app/cdk-drag-drop-sorting-example.html

using the activeNote option with the *cdkDragPreview directive and the (cdkDragStarted) event. thanks !

Comment: *cdkDragPreview is another great option. We're just focused on the display at the selectbox. Anyways, glad I could help :)

Comment: @tech-no-logical I believe you could report this as a bug on the github repo: https://github.com/angular/material2/issues I wouldn't expect the selects to react this way at all. Im looking into it myself with little luck as to why it's happening. The preview is a nice work around though.

Answer (score 0):

your code is fine nothing wrong with it but this issue if called it so, caused by `drag-drop cdk` as this's the default behavior as i know but you can work around to enhance that behavior to make it looks good to the user.

try this

```
<div class="example-box" *ngFor="let item of myForm.get('items').controls" cdkDrag #elem="cdkDrag">
  <span cdkDragHandle>drag</span>
  <div [formGroup]="item">
    <input type="text" formControlName="name">
    <select formControlName="note">
      <option [hidden]="elem.moved">dragging...</option>
      <option>foo</option>
      <option>bar</option>
      <option>baz</option>
      <option>quux</option>
     </select>
  </div>
</div>
```

what happened here to things `#elem="cdkDrag"` added to drag element as `local reference`
 and `<option [hidden]="elem.moved">dragging...</option>` what gonna happen here is when the user drag the element `dragging select option` will show in `select input` when user end the dragging it will hide again and select input value will set again with some css it will looks good.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that `mat-select` from Angular Material works fine, see https://ngfelixl.github.io/ng-libraries